# Transparent Alpha Channel Video works on Windows and Android but not on iOS and iPhone Safari browser, any fix?

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, aframe

I faced a problem to display tranparent alpha channel video on web browser. It is working on windows, android, but not working on ios and iphone safari browser. I am using webm and mov video files.
I used this material shader from this repository
https://github.com/balataca/aframe-transparent-video-shader

```
<a-scene mindar-image="imageTargetSrc: {{asset('media/target'.$projectId.'.mind')}}; filterMinCF:0.001; filterBeta: 0; uiScanning: no" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;" embedded         device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: false" arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam">
    <a-assets>
        <video id="mytarget" playsinline webkit-playsinline>
            <source src="file_name.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="file_name.mov" type="video/quicktime">
        </video>
    </a-assets>
    <a-entity id="mytargetid" mytarget="" mindar-image-target="targetIndex: 0" >
        <a-video  webkit-playsinline=""  playsinline="" src="#mytarget" position="x y z" width="width" height="height" material="transparent:true; shader: transparent-video alphaTest: 0.9">
        </a-video>
    </a-entity>
    <a-camera position="0 0 0" look-controls="enabled: false" cursor="fuse: false; rayOrigin: mouse;" raycaster="far: 100000000; objects: .clickable" camera="" rotation="0 0 0 " wasd-controls="">
    </a-camera>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: It does not work for only iphone13/14, ios 16.4